# Month year back (SQL)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I m trying to dig more in the SQL query , I'm with it.

```
Yearmo      Back_1_month
-------     ------------
 201202      201201            Where 201202 is Feb 2012 , 201201 is Jan 2012
 201201      201112            
 201204      201203            
 201212      201211
```

I m confused , how can make it for 201201.

Comment: Does yearmo is a date field?

Comment: Are you actually storing the dates as 6-digit numbers? If so, why? Store it as a date (say 1st of the month) and then you can use all the wonderful date manipulation functions that your SQL server provides. Doing it by hand is always going to be slower and more error-prone. You're probably also missing out on some performance as the numbers will never be evenly spread (eg the jump from `201212` to `201301`). This _will_ come back to bite you at some point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works in one single sql query :

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), DATEADD(month, -1 , convert(datetime, CAST ( 201201 AS VARCHAR(8)) + '01', 112) ) , 112)
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `yearmo` is an `int`:

```
DECLARE @Yearmo INT
SET @Yearmo = 201201

-- First, convert yearmo to a varchar.
-- Next, add a "day" portion to the varchar.
-- Then, convert to a date.
-- Then, subtract a month.
-- Finally, convert back to your original format using char(6).
SELECT CONVERT(
    CHAR(6), 
    (DATEADD(MONTH, -1, CAST(CAST(@YearMo AS VARCHAR) + '01' AS DATETIME))), 
    112
)
```

Answer (score 1):

To substract a month, you can use [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) like this

```
SELECT DATEADD(month, -1, yearmo)
```

But then you will need to format your date and you might need to cast `yearmo` as a datetime if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT yearmo, 
LEFT(CONVERT(CHAR(8), DATEADD(month, -1, CONVERT(datetime, yearmo + '01')), 112), 6)
FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/594c5/16)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Stored Procedure with argument as yearmo and then save substring(yr) and substring(mo) in two variables and then see, if substring(mo) is 01 then decrement substring(yr) after casting and change substring(mo) to 12 and then append both substring and return.